# Undefined value ajax JQuery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, undefined

HELP!
Undefined values for all fields

```
function UpdateData(){
var id         = $('#id').attr('value');
var name       = $('#name').attr('value');
var department = $('#departament').attr('value'); 
var phone      = $('#phone').attr('value');
var mail       = $('#mail').attr('value');

$.ajax({
    url: 'updatePersonal.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: "submit=&name="+name+"&department="+department+"&phone="+phone+"&mail="+mail+"&id="+id,
    success: function(datos){
        alert(datos);
        consultingData();
        $("#form").hide();
        $("#table").show();
    }
});
return false;}
```

When I call the function it doesn't work, the value stored in the db is undefined for all fields and I tried to solve it by adding {} to the string on data: -->

`data: {"submit=&name="+name+"&department="+department+"&phone="+phone+"&mail="+mail+"&id="+id},`

but if I do that, the next part is not executed

```
success: function(datos){
        alert(datos);
        consultingData();
        $("#form").hide();
        $("#table").show();
    }
```

updatePersonal.php -->

```
<?php
require('functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require('clases/personal.class.php');
    $objPersonal = new Personal;

$id             = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['id']));
$name           = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']));
$department     = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['department']));
$phone          = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone']));
$mail           = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['mail']));


if ($objPersonal->actualizar(array($name,$department,$phone,$mail),$id) == true){
    echo 'Saved';
}else{
    echo 'There was an error...';
}
}else{
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

    require('clases/personal.class.php');
    $objPersonal = new Personal;
    $consult     = $objPersonal->show_person($_GET['id']);
    $personal    = mysql_fetch_array($consult);


  ?>
<form method="post" action="updatePersonal.php" onsubmit="UpdateData(); return false">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $personal['id']?>" />
    <p>
    <label>Name<br />
    <input class="text" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $personal['name']?>" />
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>Department<br />
    <input class="text" type="text" name="department" id="department" value="<?php echo $personal['department']?>" />
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>Phone<br />
    <input class="text" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $personal['phone']?>" />
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>Mail<br />
    <input class="text" type="text" name="mail" id="mail" value="<?php echo $personal['mail']?>" />
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Send" />
    <label></label>
    <input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="Cancel()" />
    </p>
</form>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us your `updatePersonal.php` file...

Comment: ProTip: Use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`.

Comment: `data: {"submit=&name="+name+"&department="+department+"&phone="+phone+"&mail="+mail+"&id="+id}` isn't valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: I just edit the code in my question so you can see the updatePersonal.php, also I just change the .val

I didn't know that {} cause invalid syntax, I'm sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` should be in JSON format:

`{"submit": "", "name": name, "department": department}`

and so on..

Comment: You meant `datos`, isn't it?

Comment: I've tried but the problem still remains!
when I do that the values are correctly saved in the db but the success:function doesn't work

Hope you can help me!

Comment: In the JSON object you passed to `$.ajax`, you have a `data` attribute. This is also a JSON object.

Comment: Try adding a `complete` callback and `error` callbacks as well as your `success` one. The request might have an error code.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your variables are being properly populated, maybe using a simple `alert(varname)` after the initialization... I suspect they are not being set.

Then I would suggest to try assigning the values like this:

```
var id         = $('#id').val();
var name       = $('#name').val();
var department = $('#departament').val(); 
var phone      = $('#phone').val();
var mail       = $('#mail').val();
```

Comment: I used .val(); and some alerts to check if the variables are populated, they are all set

Answer (score 0):

Use `val()` function instead of `attr()` and write param in JSON format like so:

```
function UpdateData(){
    var id         = $('#id').val();
    var name       = $('#name').val();
    var department = $('#departament').val(); 
    var phone      = $('#phone').val();
    var mail       = $('#mail').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'updatePersonal.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            department: department,
            phone: phone,
            mail: mail
        }
    }).done(function(datos){
        alert(datos);
        consultingData();
        $("#form").hide();
        $("#table").show();
    });
    return false;
}
```

Instead of fetching value for each input field and using JSON format inside data object, use `$('form').serialize()` like so

```
function UpdateData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'updatePersonal.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form').serialize()
    }).done(function(datos){
        alert(datos);
        consultingData();
        $("#form").hide();
        $("#table").show();
    });
    return false;
}
```

On `updatePersonal.php` page the `$_POST['param']` will be according to `name` attribute of input field. For eg. for `phone` input field it may be `$_POST['phone']` if the `name` attribute value will be equal to `phone`.

Search for relevant questions here, before asking any question.